Dual-function red brake/tail lights do not change brightness
My car (Renault Grand Scenic 2010) has incandescent bulb red brake/tail lights, where one bulb does double duty for both. If the headlights are on, the red brake/tail lights go on. If the headlights are off and I put my foot on the brakes, again the red brake/tail lights go on. So far, so good.
But if I have the headlights on and I put my foot on the brakes, the brightness of the red brake/tail lights does not change. The highline brake light comes on, but that's all. Clearly this is suboptimal for people following me!
I've recently changed both tail light bulbs, where one had failed and the other was dim. I'm wondering if I've got the wrong bulb here somehow, and there's some kind of dual-brightness bulb I should have bought? I've searched online and I can't find anything about that though, hence asking here.
I should mention that the bulb in question is a simple bayonet fitting with only 2 contacts, so it can't be anything like the bulb being fitted the wrong way round in a multi-way connector.

By "2 contacts", do you mean the brass shell plus one center contact at the end of the bulb? Or do you mean two side-by-side contacts on the end in addition to the brass shell? There should be two filaments visible inside the bulb. The dimmer tail light filament is 5 watts and the brighter brake light filament is 21 watts. To know what bulb to use, check the owner's manual for the bulb model number. When the bulb is replaced, it can only be inserted one way, then must be rotated about 1/6 turn clockwise to lock it in.

@MTA The former - the outer bayonet part of the bulb, plus a single centre contact.

@MTA The manual specifies a P21W, which as far as I can tell is a single element bulb.

Aren't there two bulbs for the red lenses on each side on this model? The inboard lens and bulb are for tail lights with a single filament, the outboard lens and bulb is for tail light + brake with two filaments?

@MTA No, there's only a single bulb for the red section. If it was two separate bulbs, life would be more straightforward! :) Thanks for your comment about the 21/5 bulb though - that may have pointed me at the manual being wrong. The cluster doesn't come out far enough to easily check whether there are two contacts at the bottom of the socket, so it may be that it should be a 21/5, and a regular 21 is just making contact with both. I've got new bulbs on order, and we'll see what happens. Thanks for that pointer!

Based on comments above, I was intrigued with the possibility that Renault may be using a single traditional 1-filament incandescent 21 watt bulb and modulating it to produce 5 watts of light for tail lights and 21 watts of light for brake lights. I've never seen that.
It appears to be the case in your 2010 Renault Grand Scenic. I found a Renault  forum post where your vehicle's center high brake light was working but the outboard brake lights were not, yet the tail light function worked, and apparently all on a single bulb that your manual says has a single filament.
It was the Body Control Module. After clearing two fault codes, the brake lights worked again. If you have a scan tool that can access the BCM, you should scan for faults and clear them if found. If you don't have the required scan tool to access the BCM, my crystal ball sees a mechanic in your future . . . .

As an embedded software person who's previously worked on automotive stuff, I was intrigued by that too. But it turns out it's more straightforward than that, and you were right about the different bulb.

@Graham Doh! (Slaps forehead.) I was imagining the BCM putting out PWM pulses when in taillight mode. But all's well that ends well. Glad it worked out for you, and dang that owner's manual with its bad data on replacement bulb number!

Yep, frustrating! Never mind, it's going now. And yes, I did mistrust the BCM/ABS when both lights failed, and I was wondering about it PWMing it too, which if it had gone wrong would have been pricey. But the check light on the dash lit for 5s on key-on and then went out, which it shouldn't if there's a fault. I've got a scan tool, but thankfully I didn't need to use it here.
